# Как убрать обводку при нажатии на checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Помогите пожалуйста убрать обводку при нажатии на галку, но чтобы оставалась при наведении курсора мыши и переключением tab'ом. Не получается так сделать...

```css
.select {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #cbd1d4;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 5px center;
  background-image: url("https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-homeworks/form-elements/city-select/img/select-arrows.svg")
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
}

.checkbox-text::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: url("https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-homeworks/form-elements/city-select/img/checkbox-unchecked.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 20px;
}

.checkbox:checked+.checkbox-text:before {
  background-image: url("https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-homeworks/form-elements/city-select/img/checkbox-checked.svg");
}

.checkbox:focus~.checkbox-text::before {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.checkbox:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.checkbox-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox-text:hover.checkbox-text::before {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.select:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.select:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.button:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #0f8fee;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="select-group">
        <span class="select-label">Выберите свой город</span>
        <select class="select">
          <option value="moscow" selected>Москва</option>
          <option value="st-petersburg">Санкт-Петербург</option>
          <option value="kazan">Казань</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="checkbox-group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required>
        <span class="checkbox-text">Вы согласны на обработку персональных данных</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="button">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Так у вас это не checkbox, а span, да еще и это картинка svg

Comment: `<input type='checkbox' onchange='blur();'>` так сойдёт?

Answer (score 0):

```
input.checkbox{outline:none;}
```

вроде бы так

Comment: пробовал, не помогает